# How can I get url in Gin middleware?

Tags: go, middleware, ab-testing, go-gin

I want to do a A/B test in a Gin's middleware, I want to pass `url:usermeta` as a key-value to the A/B test service. How can I achieve this goal?Or any other grace way?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to add a new functional middleware and test it in A/B style.

```golang
func ServiceMiddleWare() gin.HandleFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context){
        r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))
        if r.Intn(100) < 50 {
           c.Next()
           return
        } 

        // service_logic
        fmt.Println("add a new service")
        c.Next()
    }
}
```

Comment: not simple random strategy, sometimes related with user's metadata

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
c.FullPath()
```

for get current URL path